# A modern alternative to Euclid's definition of polygons

Tags: definition, euclidean-geometry

In [Definition I.19](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/defI19.html) Euclid defines polygons like this:

> Rectilinear figures are those which are contained by straight lines.

Figures with intersecting sides like the [pentagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagram) would probably not have qualified as polygons because there are points that are not unambiguously **contained** in the figure or not giving rise to questions like: "What's the area of a pentagram?"

I found it quite hard to give a simple and formal definition other than "no non-adjacent sides may intersect". Furthermore, it's not easy to check if a set of points given in Cartesian coordinates does qualify.

It came as an aha-experience when I suddenly saw, how easy it is to check for polygonity when the points are given in polar coordinates (resp. complex numbers):

> A *polygon* is given by $n$ arbitrary but pairwise different points $r_i e^{i \phi_i}$ with $0 \leq \phi_{i} \leq \phi_{i+1} \leq 2\pi$ for $i<n$.

Note the correspondence with

> A *line* is given by two arbitrary but different points $r_1 e^{i
>  \phi_1}$ and $r_2 e^{i \phi_2}$

So lines and polygons - when defined this way: via points and not via straight lines - are on a equal footing (both somehow first-class citizens of geometry: finite sets of points, fulfilling easy to check conditions).

I wonder if there is something deep in this observation, maybe indicating that complex numbers will be of help when understanding arithmetic and the relationship between geometry and arithmetic?

Could there have been a way for Euclid to give a definition of polygons similar-in-spirit to the one above, so the connection with complex numbers would have been discovered earlier?

Or are these considerations in fact in vain, futile, or even worse: trivial and give no deeper insight at all?

Comment: Why exactly is $\phi_i \leq \phi_{i+1} $ required? Consider the polygon $(r_1 exp(0), r_2 exp(i \pi /12), r_3 exp(0), r_4 exp( $

Comment: It's always congruent with a polygon with $\phi_i \leq \phi_{i+1}$ - maybe that's the essence.

Comment: Some point sets with $\phi_i \not\leq \phi_{i+1}$ may **not** qualify as polygons.

Comment: How do you deal with a roughly "C" shaped polygon ?

Comment: You are right, such polygons would be missed (even though Euclid would have allowed them). But I assume this is not a big problem: some concave polygons are allowed but not all of them, and finally one might be interested only in convex ones. (There's not much loss of generality, I think.)

Comment: Branko Grünbaum gives a general definition of the boundary of a polygon in terms of vertices and edges, allowing self-intersections and overlapping elements, with a view to allowing that any $n$-gon can be continuously transformed into any other. He treats polyhedral skeleta in the same way. Do some web searching for his papers on these topic ("Metamorphoses of Polygons", for instance); they're very enlightening.

Comment: What you've defined is a [star-convex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain) polygon containing the origin, which as you're aware does not cover all possible polygons.